# Class "notranslate" for google translate plugin change the css of the website

Tags: css, plugins, google-translate, machine-translation

So if I copy and paste the google translate plugin code snippet:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

It changes all my site css [from headings, animations to even boostrap css].

I did some research and ofcourse I found `class="notranslate"` and yes I applied for headings and stuff.

I will try by myself, but an answer would be cool.

Answer (score 2):

It was easy.

So for everyone who has this problem you just have to add `class="notranslate"` to the stylesheet's Link tag, for each one which actually does something on that specific page.

e.g:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Templates/CSS/bootstrap.min.css" title="standard"  class="notranslate" />
```

Comment: Does this block the Google Translate feature from your site overall? Or does this just fix the way your site is being displayed in Google Translate?

Comment: It still translates yet it fixes the bug.

Comment: That seems like a bug.

Answer (score -1):

I have solution width config javascript

```js
<script>
  $(".class-name").addClass("notranslate");
</script>
```

Comment: The question explicitly states that they have applied notranslate to no success.